# formatting json data for datatables.net

Tags: json

i have json data

```
[{"AppVersion":"v1.1","FeedbackId":228,"FeedbackType":"Error","Os":"iPad Simulator:iOS:iPad Simulator x86_64","OsVersion":"8.3","OscVersion":"11.1.10.0.0","ReportedBy":null,"Feedbackdate":"07-11-2015","ServerUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:7101/MUDRESTService/rest/v1"}]
```

and need to format it as

```
[
    [ "v1.1", "Error", "iOS", "9.2", "sales representative", "11-11-2015","http://localhost:7101/feedback" ]]
```

any advise on how can it be done.

Answer (score 0):

my question was finally answered here

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/84950#Comment_84950